# How to fix memory leak when using redux in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, memory-leaks, react-hooks

When moving pages through `NavLink`, most of the memory leak warnings disappeared when the cleanup function was used. However, when using `react-redux`, a memory leak warning occurs.
How do I create a cleanup function to get rid of this warning message?
My code is here. For this code, using `useState` instead of `useDispatch` made the warning go away.

```
function List() {
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.list);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      await dispatch(loadlist());
      setIsShow(true);
    }
    let clean = true;
    setIsShow(false);
    if (clean) load();
    return () => (clean = false);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  if (isShow) return <Table data={list} />;
  else return <Loading />;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what specific code is causing the "leak"? It typically occurs when you enqueue a state update in a asynchronous callback and a component is later unmounted before the callback is invoked. I'm guessing this code is updating the `isShow` state and unmounting the `Table` component while the `Table` component is possible loading/setting some state?

Comment: @DrewReese 
Seeing the comment and modifying `setIsShow(true)` to `if(clean) setIsShow(true)` solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, the old `isMounted` trick. Yeah, this will work in most cases. I read recently a blog snippet from Gaearon regarding this and that this warning will likely be removed in React v18 since state updates for unmounted components are ignored anyway.